Stepper Motor Identification Help
I am working on my capstone project for school and am tasked with upgrading some old Niryo One robot arms the school has. Right now I am trying to identify and gather as much information on the current specs of the robot. The company who made the robot has very little documentation on their website for this old model, and doesn't even list back info like payload capacity.
The two stepper motors I am trying to currently identify is these. I know they are NEMA 17 sized stepper, but these are the only markings on the motors and I am unable to find a datasheet for them.
Model numbers are 42BYGH1204-2C-24S2 and 42BYGH425-2C-25S2.


Any help with identifying the specs on these motors would be appreciated.

is the red wire pinched under the fan frame?

You can't really see it in the photo, but there is a slot in the 3D printed frame the fan is bolted to that provides clearance and access to the custom driver board. That is all separate from the stepper motor and was something added by the robot arm.
